# Трансляция экрана и звука системы на Android

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

Как получить поток видео с MediaRecorder и звук системы? Мне нужно получать скрин экрана и звук системы, упаковывать это все в объект и передавать на сервер. Например если получать изображение с камеры, то там есть событие которое передает byte[] data. Мне нужно тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю эта библиотека + демо приложение тебе поможет:

https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder/blob/master/README.md